# how to change line and thumb color in slider android material design?

Tags: android, slider, styles, rangeslider

i have a rangelsider created in xml like the code below

```
     <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
android:id="@+id/dataSlider"
android:layout_height="5dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:valueFrom="0.0"
android:visibility="visible"
android:valueTo="100.0"
app:values="@array/initial_slider_values"  />
```

i want to change the color of thumb circle and make it smaller, also want to change the line color , the styling doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use these attrbutes

**Tick**

```
app:tickColor
app:tickColorActive
app:tickColorInactive
```

**Thumb**

```
app:thumbColor
app:haloColor
app:thumbStrokeColor

app:thumbRadius
```

More attrbutes and implemention
https://material.io/components/sliders/android#using-sliders

Comment: thank you Ali for this great answer, the thumb color working well, the tick color is not working...please can you show me how to see all attributes of all app:

Comment: Your welcome. Read this document, it helps you https://material.io/components/sliders/android#using-sliders

Answer (score 4):

You can use  app:trackColor="Your color" for changing color of the track